# Could I use marmalade to create Service

Tags: c++, marmalade

As the title says, could I use marmalade to create a [service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)? Also could I create a service(or alternative) for multiple platforms(IOS and Windows Phone)? Just to note the language I'm planning to use is C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand so, services is an additional functionality which implemented differently on each platform, and Marmalade's abstraction layer does not provide cross-platform access to this functionality, but you can use Extensions Development Kit (EDK) for implement this. http://docs.madewithmarmalade.com/display/MD/Extensions+Development+Kit+EDK